# Optimize to Find the Mahalanobis Distance to Minimize the Term

Tags: optimization, interpolation, nonlinear-optimization, machine-learning, mahalanobis-distance

I have an optimization problem defined as following:

Assuming we have a data set $ { \left\{ \left( {x}_{i}, {y}_{i} \right) \right\}}_{i = 1}^{N} $ where $ {x}_{i} \in {\mathbb{R}}^{d} $ and $ {y}_{i} \in \mathbb{R} $.

We want to find $ \hat{C} $ minimizes the following:

$$ \hat{C} = \arg \min_{C} {\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \left( {y}_{i} - \sum_{j \neq i} exp \left( -\frac{1}{2} {\left( {x}_{i} - {x}_{j} \right)}^{T} C \left( {x}_{i} - {x}_{j} \right) \right) {y}_{j} \right)}^{2} $$

Namely finding the [Mahalanobis Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) Matrix which minimizes the term above.

I'm not experienced with Optimization and I have few questions:

- Is this a Convex problem in $ C $?
  You can assume $ C $ is a [Positive Definite Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) (As it plays a role in [Mahalanobis Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance)).
- Is it "Easy" or solvable to the least?
- If it does, how would you solve it (I'm using MATLAB)?
- Basically I'm trying to calculate a weight which is a function of $ \left | {x}_{i} - {x}_{j} \right | $, namely the distance between the vectors, is there a simpler function which could make things "Convex" and easy to solve?
- If I add the assumption of $ C $ being diagonal, how would that make things easier besides being a multiplication of exponents of weighted norms, namely, will it be convex?

Thank You!

Comment: Since $ C $ is Mahalanobis Distance Matrix is is assured to be Positive Definite Matrix and Symmetric (I don't care on the extreme cases PS matrices aren't symmetric). How can you show it is Convex?

Comment: Anyone? Please, any assistance?

Comment: Your problem has some things in common with the well known problem of finding the covariance matrix that maximizes likelihood. Google "maximum likelihood multivariate gaussian" and you should find some useful resources.

Comment: @ben, While I can see the connection if you neglect the multiplication by other terms I can't see it the way things are written above.